# What software do publishing companies use to create drawings for text books?

Tags: software

What software is used to create free body diagrams, inclines, springs and so on in the introductory physics textbooks ?

I know Adobe, Luxology, and many others could, but I am more interested in software with ready made objects, that could still create good looking diagrams with less effort. Most of the textbooks have 100s of such diagrams that are kind of good looking.

Comment: Highly relevant: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/401/