# Software packages for calculating Feynman diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, feynman-diagrams, software

I am trying to calculate the two and three-loop divergences in a certain quantum field theory.  This is beyond the domain where I can do anything by hand, and I would appreciate any recommendations for software.

One difficulty is that the theory I am considering is non-Lorentz invariant -- Lorentz symmetry is broken by a background field.  As far as I can tell it is hard to implement this in most packages.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/96510/2451

Comment: The other question is 7 years old.  Many links are dead and packages unmaintained.  I am interested in the packages available now!  Any chance you could bring this question back?