# Good Mathematica package for computing Feynman graphs (resource request)?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, feynman-diagrams, software

I was wondering if anyone had any go-to Mathematica packages for computing higher-order Feynman graphs. Specifically ones that would allow me to construct higher spin fields like $h_{\mu\nu}$ and then be able to write the rules in myself (I have the Feynman rules, I just need a nice package that understands what I am typing).

I have only ever worked with diffgeo.m before, so if that could be used alongside a Feynman graph package that would be helpful.

Comment: Might [mathematica.se] be better suited for this question about Mathematica?

Comment: @KyleKanos I'll post this over there as well, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I know people that use a package called Feyncalc for diagram computations, maybe take a look at that.

Comment: What exactly do you want? When you say 'computing higher order feynman graphs', you mean doing the loop integrals? Mathematica has various packages for handling generic one-loop integrals, two-loop and above are usually specialised

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/96510/2451

Comment: Reposted over at Mathematica: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/287477/good-mathematica-package-for-computing-feynman-graphs-resource-request