# Doing numerics in physics

Tags: resource-recommendations, soft-question, computational-physics, software

Soon, I am going to write my master thesis in theoretical physics. I assume there, and later on in my career, I will have to do more serious numerics than I did up to this point. That's why I want to find out:

**What programming languages are available for doing numerics in theoretical physics?  What are their relative strengths/weaknesses?  How do their speeds compare?**

The programming language should be able to do top performance (in the first place) and at the same time be reasonable fun to programm in. Considering the first criterion, I assume there will be a mostly not opinion-based answer to my question.

So far, for most calculations in physics, I have been using Maple and Mathematica, with which I am fairly familliar with but which do not seem to provide the performance for more serious stuff. Furthermore I know Matlab, which I am using now for a year but only for a lecture of numerics thus far (so purely for elementary problems).

Then of course I know C++, where there is a numerics package called GSL. This does not seem very handy to me on the first glance.

I never worked with python but fear, it will not provide the needed performance and will be rather a drastic change from what I used so far.

So are there other options, which I oversaw? And what is the way to go for "modern numerics in physics"? What does the answer depend on?

Comment: This really is opinion-based, as most advice-type questions are. But beyond that, it's just off topic here. It would be a good topic to bring up in [chat] though.

Comment: It is fairly undeniable that C/C++ and Fortran are your top two/three languages when it comes to performance.

Comment: This is _mostly_ a preemptive warning, but everyone, please keep in mind that the comments are not for extended discussions (of the type that I suspect is likely to start if we try to answer the question in comments).

Comment: @Hagadol You might find a lot of very useful questions on SciComp.SE http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am not quite sure if I agree with this close, as http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/401/ seems pretty parallel and is still open. Could you please clearify?

Comment: @Hagadol There is a subtle difference. Your question is "What should I use", the other is more general "Which tools ara available". (Although the other one might be closed for being a list-type question).

Comment: @Hagadol: That question was posted very early on (post 401 compared to your 126828!); a lot has changed since then.

Comment: Yes, that question was pretty old and I hadn't thought of it. I've now put a historical lock on it.