# Software for qualitative graphs/cartoons?

Tags: resource-recommendations, computational-physics, software

I have various tools at my disposal, and a lot of use cases that they don't seem ideal for.  My current application is a graduate class in chaotic systems, but this is a chronic problem for me both in class and in work.

The test problem I'm working with:

> "For the system $\dot{x} = x − rx(1 − x)$, sketch all the qualitatively different vector fields that occur as $r$ is varied."

I typically use Python and Matplotlib to graph functions.  For any other kind of visual aids, I use Inkscape, but it's often cumbersome; overkill in many respects, and without convenient shorthands in others.

Things I'd like to be able to add to an image with a click or two: Simple axes, vectors, free-body diagrams, labels, basic shapes, exact functions, any other functionality you might find in graphing software, free-drawn functions that maybe get splined/smoothed.

If it's something that's available on both mac and windows, that would be a *huge* bonus.  Any recommendations?

(I also recognize this might not be the best stack to ask this question, but I figure most of you probably have a frequent need for this sort of thing :))

Comment: [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/?lang=en-GB) and its free.

Comment: I wish there was something "simple" that can handle most scientific/engineering sketches and graphs. I haven't found one yet. Excluding graphing, you _can_ coax PowerPoint into pretty decent diagrams for FBD, velocity analysis etc. Draw an arrow, rotate 90° and you have a perpendicular, press shift and drag the ends to stretch ends etc. Use merge/cut shapes to build more complex geometries.

Comment: Have you tried Ipe (https://ipe.otfried.org/)?

Comment: @Farcher GeoGebra is promising!!  It does a lot of what I wanted and some stuff I hadn't even thought to ask for.  It looks like it's more aimed towards people teaching and learning relatively basic math than it is towards professionals, but it's pretty damn powerful at first blush.  I played around with the browser version and I'll try the offline app next.

Comment: @JAlex do you know about this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/401/what-software-programs-are-used-to-draw-physics-diagrams-and-what-are-their-rel) this is not enough for you? Frank Harris I have used vectors on Geogebra and is a nightmare a lot of bugs maybe new update solve this problems I need to recheck but I don't have a a good memories related Geogebra for drawing vectors